# How to best read a PDF on Kindle?

Tags: kindle, epub, pdf, conversion, file-format

Interested in reliable ways of converting, specifically, `PDF` files for reading on a Kindle.  See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/5429242/262852

Not looking for a steep learning curve, something pretty idiot (me) proof.

The simplest way seems to be send an e-mail to Kindle:

[Reading PDFs on Kindle device](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/15/9853)

Or is that perhaps not even necessary?  Plain `PDF` is perfectly readable as-is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kindle pdf app only works well with plain .pdf files, however, the user experience isn't that great, because the pdf app doesn't have a reflow option.

If you haven't updated your firmware to the latest firmware version, you might be able to [jailbreak](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=275881) your Kindle and to install [KOReader](https://github.com/koreader/koreader), which has a much better PDF reader. BTW, you can also read epub2 books with KOReader, as long as they don't contain RTL text (e.g., Arabic books or Japanese Mangas).